# Drupal views $title is null

Tags: views

I have created a view as a page, and set a title for it. It works fine on the view preview, but on the actual page it becomes null. The title also displays on the title bar of the browser.

I have overridden the template views-view--page.tpl, debugged the variables, and found that `$title` is `NULL`.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Also in the pre process function template_process_views_view **drupal_get_title()** is returning null value